# how to know child attributes in xml file

Tags: asp.net, xml

Part of XML:

```
<section name="header">
    <placeholder name="HeaderLeftPane"></placeholder>
    <placeholder name="HeaderCenterPane"></placeholder>
    <placeholder name="HeaderRightPane"></placeholder>
 </section>
```

in page load i have

```
   XmlDocument XD = new XmlDocument();
        XD.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Test.xml"));
    XmlNodeList nodeListName = XD.SelectNodes("layout/child::node()");
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in nodeListName)
        {   
            string name = xNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
            int  child = xNode.ChildNodes.Count;
            LblDisplay.Text += name +  child;
            LblDisplay.Text += "<br/>";
        }
```

result is`header3`.i want to catch all child `placeholder` attributes `name`.how can i catch it plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looping around all the placehoders but overriding you changes. what you need to do is in the foreach loop add the name to a list and then display that later in textbox

example

```
XmlDocument XD = new XmlDocument();
XD.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Test.xml"));
XmlNodeList nodeListName = XD.SelectNodes("section/placeholder");
IList<string> names  = new List<string>();
foreach (XmlNode xNode in nodeListName)
{
   string name = xNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
   int child = xNode.ChildNodes.Count;
   names.Add(name);
}
```

display the attributes like this

```
string nameString = string.Empty;
foreach (string name in names)
{
   nameString += name + " ";
}

LblDisplay.Text = nameString;
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply.I mean to say that i only able to count child nodes but unable to catch there attrributes name for display.in above i want to display `HeaderLeftPane` `HeaderCenterPane` `HeaderRightPane` on lblDisplay.Any idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
        XmlDocument XD = new XmlDocument();
        XD.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Test.xml"));

        XmlNodeList listChildNodes = XD.SelectNodes("//*[name()='placeholder']");

        List<string> names = new List<string>(listChildNodes.Count);
        foreach (XmlNode nodeChild in listChildNodes)
        {
            names.Add(nodeChild.Attributes["name"].InnerText);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", names.ToArray()));
```